# Is linguistically incorrect to use "basically" frequently or it's just culture

Tags: word-usage, british-english

Many young and old people use this word, regardless of their ethnic background or how wealthy they are. I disagree with the claim that it is used only by certain type of people however it does not sound like proper English. Is it wrong from English language point of view to use that word in the beginning of every conversation   ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not wrong, grammatically speaking. However, a word that gets used very often by a particular speaker starts to lose its meaning when that speaker says it, for three reasons:

1. It's not offering you any context about what they mean.
2. It leads to [*semantic satiation*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_satiation), a psychological effect that causes frequently-repeated words to be "skipped over" by your brain.
3. Many people would consider it to have an annoying, repetitive quality.

This is true in languages other than English, too. If you started all your sentences in French with "*fondamentalement, ...*" you'd have the same issues.

Answer (score 2):

It isn't *wrong*, but using the same word over and over and over isn't very interesting, either. If it's being used at the beginning of every sentence then it becomes a meaningless sound, like "um".